# Insert INTO MSSQL table FROM another table did not work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created two tables,

Table 1, `mail_groups`:

```
mail_group_id | mail_group_name
```

Table 2, `mail_recipient_list`:

```
id | mail_group_id | recipient_id
```

To insert data to `mail_recipient_list` table. I wrote following SQL, but it did not work.

```
INSERT INTO mail_recipient_list (mail_group_id, recipient_id) 
SELECT TOP 1 id FROM mail_groups WHERE mail_group_name='".$key."', '".$value."'
```

As this query I want to get `mail_group_id` from `mail_groups table`. I can get `recipient_id` from html form. **$key** is `mail_group_name`.

Can someone please advice me to fix this issue. Thank you..

Comment: what is this `mail_group_name='".$key."', '".$value."'`?

Comment: @TheFlash it looks like PHP.

Comment: @RobertColumbia is he trying to concatenate these two `'".$key."', '".$value."'` ? and then compare them with `mail_group_name`???

Comment: @TheFlash that values come from PHP , as I explained $key has mail_group_name, and $value has recipient_id.

Comment: then your second query shoud be `"SELECT TOP 1 id,'".$value."' FROM mail_groups WHERE mail_group_name='".$key."'"`

Comment: @TheFlash I tried, it is not working

Comment: check my answer and try it that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I suggested on the comments, your query should be:

```
"INSERT INTO mail_recipient_list (mail_group_id, recipient_id) 
SELECT TOP 1 id, '".$value."' FROM mail_groups WHERE mail_group_name='".$key."'";
```

Comment: Okay I now used `LIMIT` instead of TOP 1, try again

Comment: MSSQL does not support for LIMIT, they support for TOP.

Comment: my mistake i thought you are using mysql, check my answer now...it was not working before because of the missing quotes

Comment: this should work, unless your `$key` value has no match in the database.....you can also try to hardcode the variable values to see if it really works `SELECT TOP 1 id, '2' FROM mail_groups WHERE mail_group_name='your key value'`